# UIView rotate animation on a point

Tags: objective-c

How do I rotate animate a UIView but with respect of a point?
It's kinda like how the moon is rotating the earth kinda movement. It rotates around the earth as opposed to just the moon itself rotating.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you'll need to do here is use a [CAKeyframeAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/PropertyAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006672-SW11) to move your view along a path. In this case, of course, you'll use a circular path. However, you also want to rotate the view. A [CABasicAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/PropertyAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006672-SW9) should work for that. You can run both animations simultaneously using CAAnimationGroup.

Warning: I haven't tried this, so if you encounter trouble that makes you think this is the wrong path, trust that.

It seems like you might also be able to do the whole animation using a single keyframe animation on the view's `transform` property. That may or may not be the case, but calculating an array of intermediate transformation matrices doesn't seem like a lot of fun.

Let us know how it works out.